# How to handle folks posting speculative answers to an unclear question?

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts

I got me involved in a kind of war. And I am stuck what I should do now.

This question came along: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24184357/sql-split-a-string-having-delimiter.

As soon as I read the question I thought, well that is totally unclear. So I voted to close.

Soon, a few answers came in and I tried to let the people answering see it is useless to answer, since there is not enough information.

Within a few minutes, I got stuck in a war where questions from myself were gaining downvotes, people answering went upvoting each other, and I still don't have the feeling my actions helped anything to make this site better.

So to you: what should I do? Abandon, of course. But that doesn't solve the problem.

Any other thoughts?

Comment: Why did you go after the answerers for an element which the OP really should address? Why not simply ask the OP for that info. Now it comes across as you engaging in battle of sorts, rather than simply trying to clarify the situation.

Comment: True. That's probably my mistake. I thought the existing comment was sufficient for OP. The answerers though didn't seem to give anything and just post random answers.

Comment: Like the song in Disney's newest animated hit says - "Let it go!" I feel your pain though, I have been in some heated discussions over things like this.

Comment: Yeah, not arguing that you're wrong, but picking the answerers as targets and doing that for all of them .... well, that might set you up for nothing positive. I'd indeed abandon, or at most gently coax the OP into providing the required information a bit more.

Comment: If only the OP comes back to SO @Bart.

Comment: If you don't try you can be certain it won't work @JayBlanchard

Comment: Next time, downvote anonymously ;)

Comment: That's true. I stand (or sit, as it were) corrected @Bart.

Comment: Here's hoping that OP is using oracle

Comment: @MatthiasBauch: No, I was trying to make SO better, but I failed. Any I wonder what I should do different.

Comment: Still, everybody thinks I downvoted...

Comment: You scared 4 innocent newbies. After so many downvotes and comments, they will need a lot of courage to answer again on SO, if ever.

Comment: You are true that 'the meta effect' has some unwanted side effects. It isn't that I didn't try to solve it the other way around. That was then entire point of posting here. Also, most of the votes aren't mine for sure.

Comment: @PatrickHofman: You should have stopped at voting to close/downvoting and leaving a clarifying comment to the OP.  What happens after that is not your responsibility.

Comment: It occurs to me that in this case the most correct answer would have been the one that solved the problem using the latest SQL standard. (due to the tag)

Comment: Yes. An answer with only ANSI SQL would be the best answer possible now, but still not totally accurate. You just can't answer the question. That is the whole thing I wanted to point out.

Comment: @PatrickHofman: Please add pictures to your post for those not yet having the privilige of deleting / undeleting questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Generally, you should only down vote a post for its own merit. If a question is bad and needs to get removed, that alone is not a reason to down vote people who try to answer it.

*However*, if the question is unclear and cannot possibly be answered in its current form, then down votes of answers may be justified in case the answerer is just speculating or posting opinions, but also if they are posting something technically specific beyond what the question specified.

For example, if the OP only mentions SQL and someone gives a specific answer that only applies to MySQL, you are correct in down-voting them. So you were correct in your approach.

Just a note: remain as polite and professional as possible in case a debate about down votes comes up, since nobody likes getting down votes. It is very easy to get drawn into some "flaming" war, in which case it is probably better to just leave the down vote as it is and step away from the post.

Comment: Note that you're assuming the OP downvoted the answers.

Comment: @Bart Fair enough, but why does it matter? _I_ down voted several of those answers after reading this post. As for the OP, got drawn into the down vote debate, so my advise is sound, whether he actually down voted or not. I've gotten into such debates myself on several occasions and nothing good ever comes out of it.

Comment: I think you should either downvote or comment.

Comment: Sure, but some of the flack the OP seems to be getting is based on the assumption he downvoted all posts. And you're reinforcing that assumption in your answer. Just stating that there is no proof of that.

Comment: NO, there is nothing wrong with giving an answer that only applies to a specific subset of the possible answers.

Comment: If a question is so bad that it is unanswerable (due to lack of information), then by definition, all of the answers *must* be bad, because the question isn't answerable.  The fact that the question is bad tell you that the answers are going to be bad even before you read them.  (Now I would read the answers just to be sure they didn't notice some information in the question I didn't see, but still.)

Answer (score -7):

There is nothing wrong with them giving the answers, even not knowing the specific platform, as long as they note the platform their answer is targeting.  Even if they don't, it's not that bad either since the OP is responsible for giving the needed information, and any info they don't give would just have to be assumed.

There are a lot of SQL questions that don't mention the platform used, and there is nothing wrong with giving an answer for just a specific subset of a problem.